# Class Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

I'm new to python and trying to get a list of the classes an object's class inherits from. I'm trying to do this using the `bases` attribute but I'm not having any success. Can someone please help me out?

```
def foo(C):
     print(list(C.__bases__))

class Thing(object):
    def f(self):
        print("Yo")

class Shape(Thing):
    def l(self):
        print("ain't no thang")

class Circle(Shape):
    def n(self):
        print("ain't no shape")

test = Circle()
foo(test)
```

Answer (score 6):

Only classes have `__bases__`; class instances do not. You can get the class object through an instance's `__class__`: use `foo(test.__class__)` or `foo(Circle)`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `inspect`, from [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro)

> Return a tuple of class cls’s base classes, including cls, in method
>   resolution order. No class appears more than once in this tuple. Note
>   that the method resolution order depends on cls’s type. Unless a very
>   peculiar user-defined metatype is in use, cls will be the first
>   element of the tuple.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(test.__class__)
(<class '__main__.Circle'>, <class '__main__.Shape'>, <class '__main__.Thing'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```

This traverses up the inheritance hierarchy & prints all classes, including `object`. Pretty Cool eh ?

Comment: +1 since it returns a list of all of the classes. In order to get it to work with the OP's example, I believe it should be `test.__class__` since `test` is an instance in his case?

Comment: yes it should be `test.__class__`, was in a hurry to answer :)

Comment: Assuming it's a new-style class, `test.__class__.__mro__` should also work. The reason to use `getmro` is that it [handles old-style classes as well](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/inspect.py#l332). It first looks for `__mro__`, and if it doesn't find it, it assumes the class is an old-style class and recursively searches the `__bases__` hierarchy. If you don't need that functionality, then you can avoid an import.

Comment: yes i forgot about that, thanks for pointing out. But my philosophy is, when there is a method in the core lib which does this (& also provides backward compatibility) why should I write my own.

Comment: I see your point -- certainly you're right importing `getmro` makes more sense than defining `foo` as above.

Answer (score 2):

```
print '\n'.join(base.__name__ for base in test.__class__.__bases__)
```

Or, using the `inspect` module:

```
from inspect import getmro
print '\n'.join(base.__name__ for base in getmro(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `foo` works.  But you need to pass a class to `foo`, not an instance.

```
In [1]: def foo(C):
   ...:          print(list(C.__bases__))
   ...:

In [2]: class Thing(object):
   ...:         def f(self):
   ...:                 print("Yo")
   ...:

In [3]: class Shape(Thing):
   ...:         def l(self):
   ...:                 print("ain't no thang")
   ...:

In [4]: class Circle(Shape):
   ...:         def n(self):
   ...:                 print("ain't no shape")
   ...:

In [5]: test = Circle()

In [6]: foo(test)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7b85deb1beaa> in <module>()
----> 1 foo(test)

<ipython-input-1-acd1789d43a9> in foo(C)
      1 def foo(C):
----> 2          print(list(C.__bases__))
      3

AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute '__bases__'

In [7]: foo(Thing)
[<type 'object'>]

In [8]: foo(Circle)
[<class '__main__.Shape'>]

In [9]: foo(Shape)
[<class '__main__.Thing'>]
```

Comment: Ah thank you all. Much appreciated. I didn't understand that objects didn't have bases